# MPMoviePlayerController multiple video play

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using MPMoviePlayerController for playing video. Now I want to play multiple video in loop. Here is my code:

```
self.movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"My Video Path"];
    [self.movieController setContentURL:url];
    [self.movieController.view setFrame:CGRectMake (0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 370.0f)];
     self.movieController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    [self.movieController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
   // self.movieController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [self.view addSubview:self.movieController.view];

    [self.movieController play];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.movieController];

- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

[self.movieController stop];
[self.movieController.view removeFromSuperview];
self.movieController = nil;

}
```

It is working fine for 1 video. Now, suppose I have two URLs which will play automatically  one after another. How should I do it?

Comment: Please review this lik: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823683/playing-multiple-videos-using-mpmovieplayercontroller

Answer (score 1):

On `MPMoviePlayerController` you need to `setContentURL` each time you want to change the video. I'd suggest on `moviePlayBackDidFinish` don't kill the player but add another 
`[self.movieController setContentURL:url];`
and 
`play` (or `prepareToPlay`)

It won't happen immediately, so maybe you'll need a `UIActivityIndicatorView`

**Edit** :

Option number 2, if you want to use `AVPlayer` directly - you have [AVQueuePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if (needNextPlay) {
        MPMoviePlayerController *player = (MPMoviePlayerController *)[notification object];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your new Video Path"];
        [player setContentURL:url];
    } else {
        [self.movieController stop];
        [self.movieController.view removeFromSuperview];
        self.movieController = nil;
    }

}
```